# Как программно узнать dpi экрана?

Tags: java, android

Как программно узнать dpi экрана в JAVA под Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [android dpi programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20dpi%20programmatically)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166582/3212712
3. `DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();`